# Google Script : How to prevent the 2nd execution of script function while the 1st is still running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script function connected to a button in a google sheet.
If the user click 2 times on the button, the script will be launch 2 times, so the 2 same scripts are running almost simultaneously.

I would like to prevent this. If the user click on the 2nd time on the button, while the 1st one is still running, then the 2nd click should be ignored.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual script, how about using LockService? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Comment: Share a sample of the code and folks will be able to help you!

Comment: It's always recommended to post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. That way the community can help you in a better way.